# Pass a value globally

Tags: c#, xamarin

Im new to xamarin/c#, im trying to make an application with login , and Im trying to pass the logged in userid inside the application, the question is , how do I pass or make the user id keeps floating inside after the login page? Should I keep passing it in every page using queryproperty or there's better way to keep it , like a specific file to to put it so that every page can call it?

Comment: Xamarin doesn't use query parameters (or URLs) to identify pages

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Application.Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.properties?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Application_Properties) collection to store things that need to be accessible to the entire application.

To store the user ID you would use

```
Application.Current.Properties("UserID") = UserID;
```

and to retrieve it you would use

```
UserID = Application.Current.Properties("UserID");
```

Comment: Note that these will survive an app-restart. This may or may not be what is needed

Answer (score 1):

In `C#` it's not possible to define true global variables (meaning that they don't belong to any class). using a `static class` is a valid alternative option so you can create something like this:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public Dictionary<int, UserObject> Users = new Dictionary<int, UserObject>();
}
```

Now, you'll be able to access The Users's dictionary property and add/remove/modify login users

Following Hans Keﬆing comment, Please note that An Xamarin app servers a single user at at time, so you can refactor the above from a `dictionary` to `UserObject`

Comment: A Xamarin app servers a single user at at time, so a plain "UserObject" property would be enough

Comment: I refactored my answer @HansKeﬆing, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

Static classes - bad practic for contains info. You can use `IoC-container`. I don't know xamarin, if you have `startup-class` (how WPF), you can make ioc-container:

1. Install Autofac `Install-Package Autofac -Version 5.0.0`
2. Rigster user content:

```
class StartupClass
{
   public static IContainer Container { get; set; }

   public void OnStartup()
   {
      var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
      var userContent = smthMethodForGiveUserContent();
      containerBuilder.RegisterInstance<User>(userContent); //register UserType!
      Container = containerBuilder.Build();
   }
}
```

3. Resolve user content:

```
class SmthClass
{
   public void Method()
   {
      using(var scope = StartupClass.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
      {
          var userContent = scope.Resolve<User>(); //IT'S YOUR OBJECT, USE!!
          //smth code..
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to define a variable in `App`, it can be accessible to the entire project .

Because `App` itself has been defined inside `Application` class ,and it is a `static` property .

```
public partial class App : Xamarin.Forms.Application
{
    public string UserID;
}
```

```
// set or get
(App.Current as App).UserID
```